# Javascript - take every fifth number from an input list

Tags: javascript

Say I have an input consisting of 30 numbers, and I want the 1st, 5th, 10th, 15th, etc - all in one output. How would I do this?

Comment: Please provide an example of what form your input is (HTML or Javascript data).

Comment: What's "input"? `"12 123 123"`, `[1, 2, 34, 4,5]`, or ...?

Comment: Some code to identify what you are trying do would help. Also, how is the input format? From where are we getting the input.

Comment: Have spotted the possible error in your sequence ? 1st-5th and 5th-10th are not the same distance ;)

Comment: Downvoting.  Question unclear and OP hasn't responded to clarifying questions after 13 mins.  Come on people.  If you ask a question, follow up immediately to see if people understand it and what questions they have.

Comment: sorry guys, had to step out a min. Input is a list delimited by spaces - "1 2 3 4 5 6" etc. Re gaby, yes I know, but I still need the first item in the list. Thanks everybody for getting back to me so fast - joe

Comment: @jamesson given a whitespace-delimited list "1 2 3 4 5 6", *2* is the first item in the list. Is that what you want?

Comment: no, I meant zeroth. Sorry I was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input can be expressed as an array, this simplest solution would be to use the `Array.filter` method:

```
var filterNotMultFive = function(val, idx, arr) { return !(val % 5); };
inputArray.filter(filterNotMultFive);
```

Caveats: Based on your question I assume you mean to test *values*, not *indices*. If you want indices, use

```
var filterIdxNotMultFive = function (val, idx, arr) { return !(idx % 5); };
```

I also assume you mean to start at the *zeroth*, not the first.

Edit: based on input delimited by spaces in comment above, assuming you want output delimited by spaces, just use the array.join method to rejoin the output with a single white space. Then assign the result to a variable.

```
var outputDelimitedBySpaces = inputDelimitedBySpaces.split(/\s+/).filter(filterNotMultFive).join(" ");
```

Comment: kojiro - many thanks for the assist, just bear with me a moment since I'm a little inexperienced with this function as a variable thing. I assume val, idx, and arr are arguments - but what do you do with them? Also, what is the output? how would I put it in a variable?

Comment: Most of the iteration methods for Arrays take three arguments: The current value for that iteration, the current index for that iteration, and the entire array. You can call them anything you like, but I think val, idx, arr, is a good compromise between pith and readability. You don't have to use all or any of them. In this example I'm only using val. As far as putting the output into a variable, I'll edit the above to demonstrate. [More info at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: again, thanks tons for the help. Now if I wanted to handle the iterator value as user input, ie let the user choose 6th, 7th, 8th etc.?

Thanks again